# Why am I getting error "use of undeclared identifier?"

Tags: c, for-loop, identifier, cs50

I have searched and can't work out why why I am getting this error if it is declared within the for loop?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char* sur;
    char* space = " ";
    char* name = GetString();

    printf("%c\n", name[0]);

    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(name); n < i; i++);
    {
        if (strcmp(name[i],space)==0)
        {
        sur = name[i + 1];
        }
        else
        {
        return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", sur);
}
```

Comment: what error? on what variable? is this the working version or the failing one?

Comment: for variable `n`, i guess?

Comment: When asking about error message, **always** include the **complete** error message in your question. Please [edit] your post and add it there.

Comment: `for(int i = 0, n = strlen(name); n < i; i++);` remove last `;`. Also `n < i;` --> `i < n;` and `if (strcmp(name[i],space)==0)` --> `if (name[i] == ' ')`

Comment: ...because the loop already terminated, `i` has gone out of scope.

Comment: Where is n declared?

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra semicolon after your loop declaration:

```
for(int i = 0, n = strlen(name); n < i; i++);
```

this will cause your variables `i` and `n` to be undeclared in your expected loop body

Answer (score 2):

The reason is `;` at the end:

```
//...
for(int i = 0, n = strlen(name); n < i; i++)
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  for(int i = 0, n = strlen(name); n < i; i++);
```

You CANNOT place a semi-colon at the end of the `for`-loop declaration.  The `;` is a valid statement, and because C/C++ allows you omit curly braces `{}` when using single-statements for the bodies of loops (and `if` statements), this means you have a for-loop over an empty body!  Do this instead:

```
 for(int i = 0, n = strlen(name); n < i; i++)
```

Another tip: define your variables outside of your `for`-loop and just initialize the counter in the `for` statement.

```
int n = strlen(name);
int i;
for(i = 0; n < i; i++)
```